# Bootstrap fullscreen modal not working when trying to implement it with Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a section of my about page using a full screen modal but the modal is only opening/ showing in a small section. It only opens up a little bit when I use 'modal-dialog modal-lg' but it doesn't expand besides that. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```
<!--1-->

  <div class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center mr-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 py-5 px-5">
        <img src="assets/img/bee.jpg" alt="image" class="img-fluid rounded" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-5 ">
      <h3 class="mt-4 font-weight-bold">About Us</h3>
         <p class="text-justify pt-0 mr-5"> is a publishing company working with a non- denominational ministry. 
        
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Load More
</button>
```

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-xxl-down">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Encounter the same issue. This is most likely a bug. However, you can probably add custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your bootstrap class form this :

`<div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-xxl-down">`

To this :

`<div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">`

Also be sure that you have **Bootstrap version 5** installed in your laravel project. Fullscreen modals are only included by default in Bootstrap 5 not in the previous ones: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#fullscreen-modal

Comment: I just used <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">. Now to find a way of how to expand it to cover the fullscreen.